# Split data across multiple rows in a single statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query

I have data in table like

| Customer | Invoice No | Date | Value | Paid | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 1 | 01/12/2020 | 25 | 0 | 25 |
| ABC | 2 | 01/12/2020 | 50 | 0 | 50 |
| XYZ | 3 | 02/12/2020 | 200 | 0 | 200 |
| XYZ | 4 | 04/12/2020 | 100 | 0 | 100 |
| ABC | 5 | 04/12/2020 | 500 | 0 | 500 |

Now I received amounts for customers as below

ABC 540
XYZ 210

| ABC | XYZ |
| --- | --- |
| 540 | 210 |

After receiving the amounts my table should like this

| Customer | Invoice No | Date | Value | Paid | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 1 | 01/12/2020 | 25 | 25 | 0 |
| ABC | 2 | 01/12/2020 | 50 | 50 | 0 |
| XYZ | 3 | 02/12/2020 | 200 | 200 | 0 |
| XYZ | 4 | 04/12/2020 | 100 | 10 | 90 |
| ABC | 5 | 04/12/2020 | 500 | 465 | 35 |

I got some [clues](https://andrewtuerk.wordpress.com/2013/01/17/splitting-allocations-across-multiple-records-in-a-single-statement/) but this works only for date based values but I need customer and date based.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Create a [mcve] please

Answer (score 1):

You have a fairly involved problem with not a lot of details but I think I understand what you're trying to accomplish and the solution is not simple.

You have a two step process. The first step is using [`PIVOT` or `UNPIVOT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15) to transpose the customer amounts data you received so that the column headers become values in a column called `Customer` and the `TotalValue` is in its own column.

The second step is using a [**recursive CTE**](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-recursive-cte/) to iterate over each row of each Customer and setting the `Balance` and other fields accordingly, with your base case being when the `Balance` becomes <= 0 OR `TotalValue` = 0.

I think you'll need to use a separate **recursive CTE** for each Customer (since they each have their own `Balance`) otherwise there is no fitting base case.

Comment: I will try this one. But with clues above  I managed with loop with each customer and its working fine but sometimes its takes long time to achieve the task. Actually i am working on ageing analysis report and reports showing due balance for customers

Comment: @AsimShahzad Sounds good. You might also want to look into [**Dynamic SQL**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/dynamic-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) as a way to generate the SQL script for you for each customer, instead of looping. This may improve your performance if your bottleneck is due to the loop, but it really depends on where the bottleneck is and what the **execution plan** shows.